# Yaws - start of server from current directory

Tags: erlang, yaws

I know that can add set of docroot in yaws.conf but this not always convenient. Is exist way to start of server from current directory with yaws without modifying configuration file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options:

1. Keep a template of your `yaws.conf` file somewhere and invoke `yaws` through a script that first uses the template to create a conf file with the current working directory filled in as `docroot`, and then runs `yaws` using its `--conf` command-line option to specify the newly-created conf file as its configuration file.
2. Run `yaws` in [embedded mode](http://yaws.hyber.org/embed.yaws), which allows you to programmatically specify the configuration. You can use [`file:get_cwd/0`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/file.html#get_cwd-0) to obtain the pathname of the current working directory, then use it as the value for `docroot` in the configuration details you pass to `yaws_api:embedded_start_conf/1,2,3,4`.